# Updating Fulltextsearch index immediately - SQL SERVER 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, full-text-search

I have created a Full-Text Search Index on SQL Server 2012. It was working fine until I had to remove a column from Table that was included in FullTextSearch.

Then I tried deleting existing Full Text Index & Catalog, and then recreating it. But somehow after recreating it didn't show any results for Search Query (for which earlier results were coming).

I ran following query to know the status for Full-Text-Search:

```
declare @id int
select @id = id FROM sys.sysobjects where [Name] = 'TableName'
select 'TableFullTextBackgroundUpdateIndexOn' as 'Property', objectpropertyex(@id, 'TableFullTextBackgroundUpdateIndexOn') as 'Value'
union select 'TableFullTextChangeTrackingOn', objectpropertyex(@id, 'TableFullTextChangeTrackingOn')
union select 'TableFulltextDocsProcessed', objectpropertyex(@id, 'TableFulltextDocsProcessed') 
union select 'TableFulltextFailCount', objectpropertyex(@id, 'TableFulltextFailCount') 
union select 'TableFulltextItemCount', objectpropertyex(@id, 'TableFulltextItemCount') 
union select 'TableFulltextKeyColumn', objectpropertyex(@id, 'TableFulltextKeyColumn') 
union select 'TableFulltextPendingChanges', objectpropertyex(@id, 'TableFulltextPendingChanges') 
union select 'TableHasActiveFulltextIndex', objectpropertyex(@id, 'TableHasActiveFulltextIndex') 
union select 'TableFulltextPopulateStatus', objectpropertyex(@id, 'TableFulltextPopulateStatus')
```

It returned following results:

[image]

I ran following query to drop & recreate Full-Text Search Catalog & Index:

```
        GO
    EXEC sp_fulltext_database 'enable'
    GO
    DROP FULLTEXT INDEX ON [AT].[TableName]
    GO
    DROP FULLTEXT CATALOG [table_search_catalog];
    GO
    CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG [table_search_catalog] WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = ON;

    GO
    DECLARE @Const Varchar(150)
    DECLARE @Query1 Varchar(MAX)

    SELECT @Const=TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS TC
    INNER JOIN
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS KU
    ON TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' AND
    TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = KU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    and ku.table_name='TableName'
    ORDER BY KU.TABLE_NAME, KU.ORDINAL_POSITION;


    SET @Query1 ='CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [AT].[TableName]
     ( 
      UserName
         Language 1033,
      ResumeTitle
         Language 1033,
      Address1 
         Language 1033,
      OtherSNSURL 
         Language 1033,
      LinkedInURL 
         Language 1033,
      FacebookURL 
         Language 1033,
      TwitterURL 
         Language 1033, 
      SkypeID 
         Language 1033, 
      comments 
         Language 1033, 
      CurrentCompany 
         Language 1033, 
      PreviousCompany 
         Language 1033
     ) 
      KEY INDEX '+@Const +'
          ON table_search_catalog
       WITH STOPLIST = SYSTEM, CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO'

    EXEC (@query1)


    GO
    Update [AT].[TableName] SET UserName=UserName;

    GO
    ALTER INDEX ALL ON AT.TableName
    REORGANIZE; 

    GO
    ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [AT].[TableName]
       SET CHANGE_TRACKING MANUAL;

    GO
    ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [AT].[TableName]
       START FULL POPULATION;

    GO
    ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [AT].[TableName]
       START update POPULATION;

    GO
    ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [AT].[TableName]
       SET CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO;
```

Clearly, Fulltext search index contains the records to be processed but after a while it remained same.

**Please let me know how much time it generally takes to process a record?
Also what should be done to immediately process the pending records(Query for this will be awesome)?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually after 20 minutes, I ran the query to see the changes & found that all the pending records have been processed. But still it took much amount of time to reflect the changes.

Thanks